# Can’t rewrite to /index.php in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mamp

This baffles me.
This is my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$0  [B,L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```

This gives me a 500 server error. But if i remove the "/" from "/index.php?__pat..."
it works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          index.php?__path__=$0  [B,L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```

This is a problem, as the *thing* I’m trying to setup requires me to have that slash.
I’m using the latest version of MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your rule is looping. The rewrite engine continues to run all the rules until the URI stops changing, and your pattern `(.*)` matches `/index.php`, so the rule keeps getting applied. You can try adding a couple of conditions to the last rule to prevent the looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          index.php?__path__=$0  [B,L,QSA]
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          index.php?__path__=$0  [B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why would the pattern ^(.*)$ mathch /index.php but not index.php, why would it only be looping when the prefixing slash i present?

Comment: @SigurdB.Svela It's a little confusing, but if you turn on rewrite logs you'll see that apache does some stripping of slashes off and that bypasses looping sometimes. Because the target doesn't have a slash, and that matches a stripped slash URI, then looping stops